# RegEx for not expecting special character excluding single quote

Tags: regex

I googled this but it's not working fine.

Please provide me a better solution.

I use this `^([a-zA-Z]+)$` but it is not excepting single quote.

I only allow the string for example `aaa'bbb`.

Comment: What's wrong with `^([a-zA-Z']+)$`

Comment: try ```^([a-zA-Z\']+)$```

Comment: This is a very basic question, to get started with regexes look at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)** and particularly the Character Classes part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below regex. It will take any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) thrice and then quote and again any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace)

aaa'bbb

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this "^([a-zA-Z\']+)$" as regular expression string to allow single quote in your input string.

Here is an example.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s= "Abc'abc";
    System.out.println(s.matches("^([a-zA-Z]+)$"));//Output will be false will not allow single quote in input
    System.out.println(s.matches("^([a-zA-Z\\']+)$"));//output will be true will ALLOW single quote in input
}
```

Best luck
Anant